# Shell Script String extraction

Tags: shell

I'm getting string from some service something like this,

```
{"statusCode":200,"statusText":"OK","responseEntity":{"authMethod":"Bearer","encodedHeader":"SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk","expiresDate":"2017-10-16T14:58:24.697Z"}}
```

I want to extract encodedHeader value which

```
SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk
```

I tried sed with version I know but no luck.
any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `AWK`.

```
~$ myline={"statusCode":200,"statusText":"OK","responseEntity":{"authMethod":"Bearer","encodedHeader":"SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk","expiresDate":"2017-10-16T14:58:24.697Z"}}
```

And

```
~$ echo $myline  | awk -F[:,] '{print $9 }'
```

Ouputs:

```
SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk
```

[:,] Match a single character present in the list.

`,:` are the field separators and the field you want is number 9.

Comment: You can always accept as an answer if it does what you wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `awk` then

```
awk 'match($0,/"encodedHeader":"([^"]*)"/,arr){print arr[1]}' <<<"$line"
```

Test Results:

```
$ line='{"statusCode":200,"statusText":"OK","responseEntity":{"authMethod":"Bearer","encodedHeader":"SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk","expiresDate":"2017-10-16T14:58:24.697Z"}}';
$ awk 'match($0,/"encodedHeader":"([^"]*)"/,arr){print arr[1]}' <<<"$line"
SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk
```

Comment: Beginner I would recommend that you use @3161993  solution +1 :) . You don't have to worry about he number of fields being changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\" '{print $16}' file

SCBjYjA5MTEtNTFjZi00ZTBjLWFmN2UtMzFhDTYzYzA3EjFk
```